# GCP, is there a way to find which Asset-type can be labelled and which are not?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I need to find out which resources (Asset-Types) in entire GCP organization can be labelled.
In short, i do not want resources which doesn't have a column Label in the schema. Is there a way to find columns of every asset-type ? or any other way to extract only resources that have column/attribute Label?

gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=organizations/Org-ID 
--filter=-labels:* --format='csv(name, assetType, labels)' --sort-by=name > notLabels.csv

i use this command to get the resources but it returns also the resources that can't be labelled.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list of services that support **labels** in GCP in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#label_support).

And you can filter it with the following format below as an example:

> gcloud asset search-all-resources  --filter labels.env:*

The above command lists the services that has **env** as `key` and anything that has `value` on it.

> gcloud asset search-all-resources --filter=-labels.*

The second sample command above lists the resources with no labels value by adding `-` before the label parameter.

You can find more information on using [filter searches using labels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources#filter) here.

Comment: i read the documents but couldn't find any way to search asset-types without labels column.

Comment: In the document they say the entire resource category that can be labelled, For example AI platform , inside which there are many resources -- MODEL can be labelled but BatchPredictions can't. i searched manually. But i need a way to find this automatically, is there a way?

Comment: I added another line of code to the answer that might help you with your use case.

Comment: I already did that if you read my question again. but this results all the resources even those that cannot be labelled (not have a column label)

Comment: It seems I missed that one, but [BatchPredictions](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/batch-predict#configuring_a_batch_prediction_job) can have labels though it is optional.